# jquery mobile using jquery to generate date-role page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm assuming this doesn't work because jquery mobile tried looking for the first `data-role` page before jquery can generate it to the `DOM`. How do i get around this? i'm planning to generate many different pages for different files.

html

```
<body></body>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var page = "<div data-role='page'>Testing</div>";
    $('body').html(page);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        //Create page variable
        var page = "<div data-role='page' id='testpage'>";
        page += "<div data-role='header'><h1>Test page!</h1></div>";
        page += "<div data-role='content'>Test content!</div>";
        page += "</div>";

        //Append to body and trigger pagecreate
        $('body').html(page).trigger("pagecreate");

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the JS code has to be inside the body.

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/EliteSystemer/ttyox641/